# How to override hardware back button of android web browser

Tags: android, button, overriding, back

I am building a mobile web site. I want to override hardware back button's click for jquery. How can I make ?

Comment: you don't. sites which "break" standard browser navigation are sites that I immediately blacklist.

Comment: @MarcB can a website do that?? From a script disable backbutton of a browser or physical device. Well thats a surprise and guess what I am joining your list